# Facebook Audience Network(FAN) Ads with Adsense ads, is it policy compliant?

Tags: google, google-adsense, advertising, facebook, mobile

In my responsive website I want to implement both Adsense and FAN on same page for mobile visitors. Is it policy compliant? I'm not using DFP.